# Java thread halting after shutdown

Tags: java, multithreading, inputstream

I've managed to configure a synchronised startup for my application, and I'm not implementing the shutdown.

I'm using a `CountDownLatch` to await the closure of all of my threads. Each thread loops until a (`volatile`) boolean, `running`, flag is set to false.

Here's an example (`Caught`)`Runnable` being ran on a thread

```
System.out.println("STARTING");
startupLatch.countDown();
final BufferedReader reader = getReader();
String line;
System.out.println("STARTED");
while (running) {
    System.out.println("WAITING FOR CLOSE");
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("WAITING FOR NO MORE LINES");
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
shutdownLatch.countDown();
System.out.println("EXITED READING THREAD: EXITS LEFT: " + shutdownLatch.getCount());
```

Initially I thought that the change to the running flag may not have been propogated to the thread, but it turns out that the thread is actually being blocked somewhere after `reader.readLine()` - thus the next iteration of the while loop can't be reached, where the `shutdownLatch` would be decremented.

My console output is:

> STARTING
>
> STARTED
>
> WAITING FOR CLOSE
>
> SHUTTING DOWN

`SHUTTING DOWN` come's from my `close` (shutdown) method.

This loop was a `while(true)` loop before I decided to implement the orderly shutdown; so, a blocking `readline` call would be fine - actually preferable to spinning off while loop iterations - because this is on another thread. However, it seem's now I *need* to spin off while loops in order to figure out when the shut down occurs.

- Is `readline` the issue here?
  if so:

  - Is `readline` supposed to be blocking?
  - How can I get around a blocking ?

Comment: Yes, `readline` is suppose to be blocking. You might consider making the `Reader` an instance field.  You could then use a method, called from another `Thread` to `close` it

Comment: It sounds like you might be using Sockets, or? If you are, you can use Socket.setSoTimeout as a more configurable (in terms of setting wait time for more input) alternative

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm using my `close` method to synchronise closure across multiple threads.

Comment: Ok, so you're closing the reader of each of those threads?

Comment: I'm releasing (independent) resources on each thread

Answer (score 0):

Use `reader.ready()` to check if the next call of `readLine()` will block the current thread

Answer (score 0):

You can have non bocking IO only on sockets. To interrupt disk operation or any other IO of a Reader the Reader thread should be interrupted. In the most cases you will get [InterruptedIOException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InterruptedIOException.html), which will break the loop.